# Signing assembly Access Is Denied

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've recently upgraded to WIndows 7. When I try to sign the assembly in VS2010 I get an "Access is denied" error. I am logged as admin so I'm puzzled. What service account does VS uses that I should elevate its privilages?

Thanks,

Risho

Comment: Question appears to be still relevant for Windows 10 Pro + Visual Studio 2019. Use sn tool to fix this as proposed by Tom Minka in comment to best answer.

Answer (score 51):

I don't know if it's Window 7 or the company policy, but I had to take ownership of the C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder and give myself full control. This corrected the issue.

Comment: Yep, this definitely works. Obnoxious problem. All you need is 'This folder only' set to 'Full Control'.

Comment: Using Windows 10 the folder differed slightly: I had to add the rights to C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys (no Application Data), but otherwise it worked as described.

Comment: @SJP FYI, C:\Users\All Users is an alias for C:\ProgramData which is visible without showing hidden system files.

Comment: For me it was 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys' but the same principle worked.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I'm running VS as admin and surely admin has full control but still getting the errors

Comment: Tried this answer but also had to launch MSVS as Admin to get farther. Now getting slightly different signing error with "Error signing assembly -- Access is denied. : failed to close the assembly module". However the .dll is not in use and is deletable.  For me it was A/V (BitDefender):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785957

Answer (score 27):

**Solution:**

Run the following command from Administrator command prompt:

For 64-bit systems:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName /v MachineKeyset /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

For 32-bit systems:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName /v MachineKeyset /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

The change affects immediately.

**Why this happens:**

MS Assembly Linker ALINK (AL.EXE) used by Visual Studio to sign assemblies creates a temporary crypto key during its work. Actually it uses some internal CLR functions for this, and the problem is that CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET flag is used by default. This requires elevation, and that's why running VS "as Administrator" works.

But, fortunately, I found that CLR has a global flag for StrongName signing, and it's stored in the system registry under

> *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName*

and is controlled by DWORD value

> *MachineKeyset*.
>
> 0 - use current user key set
>
> 1 - use machine key set (this is default)

Visual Studio is a 32-bit app and uses 32-bit version of AL.EXE for build. So on 64-bit systems it's subject to [registry redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys), and the flag is located under the key

> *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName*

It works on my VS2019, Win10, and .Net framework 4.8, but I didn't test it on previous versions though.

Comment: You can also perform these functions using the [sn tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool):
`sn -m`  displays the current value of MachineKeyset, 
`sn -m n`  sets the registry values above

Comment: On Win 64-bit it was not working until I changed both this keys.

Answer (score 2):

For windows 10 and VS 2015, I have to run VS as administrator.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I'm running VS as admin and surely admin has full control but still getting the errors.

Answer (score 2):

On Win10 I gave the user who im starting Visual Studio with, rights to **read**, **write**, run, change and display for the folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto
```