# Creation of a satellite assembly

Tags: .net, satellite-assembly

When I am trying to create a [satellite assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly#Satellite_assemblies) by using [al.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the command prompt I am getting the following error.

> ALINK: error AL1019: Metadata failure while creating assembly -- Access is
>           denied.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same error when building project have .resx files. it is caused by without permission of 'C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys'
[Signing assembly Access Is Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606342/signing-assembly-access-is-denied)
I hope this can help to your question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I also had this error when assembly signing in VS project was enabled (and no error after disabling signing). I resolved his problem by running VS 2019 as admin.

Answer (score -1):

According to MSDN, "For example, this error occurs if a file that you specify with the /win32res option is not found."

Check if all the files referenced exist, if you're creating this on a local drive (rather than a network drive), and that you have full rights to the directories involved.