# Cannot sign C++/CLI assembly in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

Using Visual Studio 2015, with the 2015 toolset: when I try to directly sign the assembly as follows:

[image: Signing a C++/CLI assembly]

The signing always fails with the following error:
`LNK1346    ALINK operation failed (80040436) : Error signing assembly -- The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

This same assembly could be signed in Visual Studio 2013 (I've just upgraded it today).

Is this a known issue in 2015 (couldn't find any bugs when I searched that error)? Or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT: Workaround**

It seems that this is yet another McAfee AV bug. However, there is another way to sign the file that might give McVirus enough time to release the lock it has taken out.

The assembly can be delay signed and `sn -R $(TargetPath) $(LinkKeyFile)` can be run as as a post build event to complete the signing. This worked for me and @Moop.

Comment: Looks like someone has a handle to the file. I would assume another tool in VS. The best way to start is to determine 'who' has the handle. Check out procexp.exe and see if any other process has an open handle to the file you are trying to sign.

Comment: Your workaround worked,it might be useful to make it into an answer to the question. Also, the $(LinkKeyFile) macro seems to work: sn -R $(TargetPath) $(LinkKeyFile)

Comment: @Moop - thanks, I've updated the question to add emphasis to the workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent solution! This was driving me crazy for months, since the linker just failed sporadically, then it worked for some hours, failed again, and I could not find the cause. We use a different virus scanner, but I guess other scanners can cause the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Works just fine on my machine, this is not a VS2015 problem.  A common environmental issue, this error message is a standard tragedy on Windows machines that are infected with shrink-wrapped malware.

Signing is a two-step process.  First link.exe has to generate the executable file, necessary so the SHA256 hash can be computed for the file.  Then the file gets re-opened by ALINK (the managed linker) to add the signature.  It has to do battle with other processes that run on your machine that are interested in the file as well.  The kind that invariably gets its underwear in bundle when an executable file appears from seemingly nowhere and insists on checking the file content and exclude access to the file until it is done.

It seems to work just fine when you use delay-signing, the delay is usually sufficient to get the process to complete its job and release the exclusive lock on the file.  Also some odds that sn.exe is a bit more sophisticated about it, retrying to open the file periodically before giving up, ALINK certainly is not.

You must make an exclusion in your anti-malware product for your build directory.  If it is some kind of aggressive freeware like Avast, AVG or ESET then plan to get rid of it asap so it can never bother you again.  Defender never gives me any trouble.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds right. We have McVirus (Afee) on our machines and it  messes with a lot of stuff. I will try to confirm on my laptop with a suitably aggressive process killer later. What confuses me is why it works fine in 2013, but not in 2015? Have there been a significant changes to link.exe and ALINK?

Comment: You can never get a diagnostic for, say, a change in a *single byte* that now makes it match a viral signature that makes the scanner look more thoroughly.

Comment: Is there any way to monitor the locks that are taken on a file? Procexp doesn't really work for locks that are taken for a short period of time so it is impossible to see what is locking the file and Resource Monitor presumably takes system-wide snapshots that means it doesn't give an accurate enough picture.

Comment: Not that I know of, the lock isn't normally held long enough to have a shot at using tooling to diagnose the evildoer.  Well, the obvious way is to follow my advice and if the problem disappears then you have a rockhard guarantee that is the anti-malware product.