# Why should we run visual studio in administrator mode...?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Visual Studio. When I tried to build my Wpf program it threw me an error

```
Error signing assembly -- Access is denied
```

But when I run Visual Studio as administrator it is running normally..

Can any one give me the reason.. TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing assembly Access Is Denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606342/signing-assembly-access-is-denied)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you need write permission on the folder. See this:

[Signing assembly Access Is Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606342/signing-assembly-access-is-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Many actions require extra priviledges. Running VS as administrator provides those priviledges otherwise VS would run as a process with limited access.